# Terminology question on sets and intersections

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

Is there a terminology for the following property:

Given $n$ sets, that for all combinations of two of them, $A_i$, $A_j$, the intersection $A_i \cap A_j$ is either the null set or equal to either $A_i$ or $A_j$.

--

The picture I had in my head was lego blocks representing the different sets.

**Set-up A** : Picture [link](http://previews.123rf.com/images/photowee/photowee1106/photowee110600049/9921463-LEGO-BLOCKS-Stock-Photo-block-building.jpg) doesn't satisfy (Red, Yellow is just one example)

**Set-up B**  Picture below satisfies the property. Intersection of any two blocks is either empty or one of the two blocks in its entirety.

[image]

Comment: Interesting. "Pairwise subsets of each other"? Whatever the answer turns out to be, it's definitely worth defining the term the first time you use it, because I (for one) don't already know it.

Comment: The most concisely I've seen such a family described is to say that the sets are "pairwise nested or disjoint."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathscr{A}$ be the family of sets. Your conditions amounts to saying that the partial order $\langle\mathscr{A},\supseteq\rangle$ is a directed forest. The example in your picture is even an arborescence (directed tree):

```
                                * light brown  
                               / \  
                              /   \  
                      yellow *     * dark brown  
                                  / \  
                                 /   \  
                            red *     * blue
```

Answer (score 0):

Take $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n$ to be sets such that if $i \neq j$ then $A_i$ and $A_j$ are disjoint (that is, $A_i \cup A_j$ is the emtpy set). Then $A_1, A_2, \ldots,A_n$ are said to be mutually disjoint.

Now if $A$ and $B$ are sets such that $A \cap B = A$ (or $B$ without less of generality) then $A$ is said to be contained in $B$, that is $$A \subseteq B.$$